# Hive - FROM <BLAH> INSERT

Tags: hive, insert

In the [Hive documentation page about dynamic partitioning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions), there is this particular example of a multi-table insert:

```
FROM S
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION (ds='2010-03-03', hr)
SELECT key, value, ds, hr FROM srcpart WHERE ds is not null and hr>10
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE R PARTITION (ds='2010-03-03, hr=12)
SELECT key, value, ds, hr from srcpart where ds is not null and hr = 12;
```

What is the `FROM S` clause all about? The multi-table insert query looks like it should work even without it, so what am I missing?

Comment: it's a bug in the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the syntax for [multiple inserts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries).If you do not want multiple passes over the Hive object,then having FROM from_statement(table,view,file,subquery) precede the multiple Insert Overwrite Table will result in a single pass over the from_statement object.

In the above example, it really should be `FROM srcpart` or it should `FROM S srcpart` which refers to Hive object S with alias srcpart from which the two partitions T & R are created.

Example

Query 1:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Raining SELECT * FROM weather WHERE rain = 1;
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Sunny SELECT * FROM weather WHERE rain = 0;
```

Query 2:

```
hive> FROM weather
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Raining SELECT * WHERE rain = 1 
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Sunny SELECT * WHERE rain = 0;
```

The query 2 will result in a single pass over table weather while the query 1 will result in 2 passes for creating the same 2 objects.